# Mimic flash code using jQuery

Tags: jquery, flash

http://www.geteyesmart.org/eyesmart/diseases/glaucoma/vision-simulator.cfm

Can anyone help me in creating the functionality shown as a flash file in above URL using jQuery?

Basically the flash shows a slider which when moved from left to right, adds a black spot on the top of the image and when the slider reaches the right most point, the entire image is covered with black background color.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you would have the ActionScript of that Flash. You would want to use the [<canvas>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial) element. There are plenty of examples and tutorials around. You can simply draw circles and stuff:

```
ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
```

Here's a [quick demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vhckuLex/1/) I made

Comment: Thanks for the demo. I tried this with an image in the background and it works when I drag the slider from left to right all the way to end. But when I drag my slider back from right to left, the effect should be removed slowly which doesn't work like it does in the URL I posted. Here is the fiddle for what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/u3cynmb2/

Comment: That's because you are drawing the black, but you do not remove it. You just have to clear the previous drawing by using `clearRect` for the whole canvas. Like this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/u3cynmb2/1/)